# Sourcemaps content same as compiled output - on Windows

Tags: node.js, gulp, source-maps, gulp-sass, gulp-sourcemaps

## The problem

I'm using `gulp-sourcemaps` to generate sourcemaps for my compiled sass.

This seems to work on linux/mac computers, but not on Windows. **Instead of the actual source sass, the content in the sourcemap is the same as the generated css**.

P.S. I do *not* want to publish and link to the actual source files. I want them embedded in the souremap.

---

## Details

Here's the full gulp task I'm using:

```js
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    gulp.src('resources/assets/sass/app.scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(sass({ outputStyle: 'compressed' }))
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(rename('css/app.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

And here's the folder structure:

```
├── gulpfile.js
|
├── resources
|   ├── assets
|       ├── sass
|           ├── app.scss
|
├── public
|   ├── css
|       ├── app.css
|       ├── app.css.map
```

---

## Even more details

I'm running Windows 7 with Node v0.12.4. The global `gulp` version is 3.9.0.

Here's my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2"
  }
}
```

Here's the original source content in `app.scss`:

```css
.div {
    color: red;

    .div {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Here's the generated CSS file:

```css
.div{color:red}.div .div{color:blue}

/*# sourceMappingURL=../css/app.css.map */
```

And finally, here's the sourcemap file (prettified):

```json
{
    "version":3,
    "sources":["app.css"],
    "names":[],
    "mappings":"AAAA,KAAK,SAAS,CAAC,UAAU,UAAU,CAAC",
    "file":"css/app.css",
    "sourcesContent":[".div{color:red}.div .div{color:blue}\n"],
    "sourceRoot":"/source/"
}
```

---

## Conclusion

As you can see from all the above, the `sourcesContent` in the sourcemap file is simply the same as the generated CSS. This makes the sourcemap pretty useless.

What am I doing wrong here, and how can I fix it?

---

Here's a download of these files: [gulp-sass-autoprefixer-sourcemaps.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6484839/gulp-sass-autoprefixer-sourcemaps.zip?dl=1).

To test: extract it, then run `npm install && gulp css`.

Comment: I copied your css and code into a fresh project and it worked as expected. `sourcesContent` is the original source. Is everything up to date?

Comment: Yes, I copy-pasted everything exactly.

Comment: @JustinHoward - Whoops. My question before was missing the `authoprefixer`, which seems to be the culprit here. Removing it does properly retain the source. I added `autoprefixer` to the question.

Comment: Okay, added your package.json with autoprefixer, and updated the gulpfile. Still works for me. `sources` shows `app.scss` and the `sourcesContent` has the original sass source. Tried on linux and mac. I don't have windows available.

Comment: @JustinHoward - hmmmm. I'm using Node `v0.12.4`. You?

Comment: I'm using the same node version. I don't think it matters but my system gulp version is 3.9.0.

Comment: @JustinHoward - I'm out of ideas. I added a [download link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6484839/gulp-sass-autoprefixer-sourcemaps.zip?dl=1) for the exact files I'm using. Do you mind trying it?

Comment: Your test zip works for me. It's possible its a windows issue. `node-sass` the libsass binary, maybe something with that? I'm stumped though.

Comment: @JustinHoward - apparently it's [a known issue](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-autoprefixer/issues/38#issuecomment-111578573) with `gulp-sass`.